# How can I "complete" a loop before moving on to the nested loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm a newbie, and I'm not sure how to properly ask this question.

I'm trying to print out the minimal number of elements possible to complete an expression. For example, 8 has one bit equal to 1 (2^3) so I want this function to only print 1. However, the function is printing three bits equal to 1 (2^2 + 2^0 + 2^0) instead. I understand why; it's because the outer loop will continue into the nested loops before completing the outer loop, but I don't know how to rearrange these loops to complete the first loop before checking the next loops.

```
var array = [];  
var countBits = function(n) {

    for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
        if (Math.pow(2,i) === n){
            array.push(i);
            return array;
        } 
        for (j=0;j<=n;j++){
            if (Math.pow(2,i) + Math.pow(2,j) === n){
                array.push(i,j);
                return array;
            }
            for (k=0;k<=n;k++){
                if (Math.pow(2,k) + Math.pow(2,j) + Math.pow(2,i)===n){
                    array.push(k,j,i);
                    return array;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

countBits(8);

console.log(array);

console.log(array.length);
```

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is very confusing! I don't have an idea what are you trying to accomplish! Can you make an algorithm and explain step by step

Comment: I think I know what's going on... Give me a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flipping the for loop direction

```
var array = [];  
var countBits = function(n) {

  for (i=n;i>=0;i--){
        if (Math.pow(2,i) === n){
            array.push(i);
            return array;
        } 
        for (j=n;j>=0;j--){
            if (Math.pow(2,i) + Math.pow(2,j) === n){
                array.push(i,j);
                return array;
            }
            for (k=n;k>=0;k--){
                if (Math.pow(2,k) + Math.pow(2,j) + Math.pow(2,i)===n){
                    array.push(k,j,i);
                    return array;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

countBits(8);

console.log(array);

console.log(array.length);
```

---

It wasn't anything to do with the order of the for loops, it was to do with the way it found the answer. You want to start with the largest possible n and work down from there.

Comment: @Shawn I dunno, I didn't look into it too much, but I assume it's because `[2,1,1]` contains numbers that are lower than the numbers in `[3]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want each round to be completed, you cannot nest them, if I understood your purpose.

Also, declare the `var i, j, k, arr = []` as variables inside the function, and let it always return the array.

```
var countBits = function (n) {
  var i, j, k, arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (Math.pow(2, i) == n){
      arr.push(i);
      return arr;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
      if (Math.pow(2, i) + Math.pow(2, j) == n){
        arr.push(i, j);
        return arr;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
        if (Math.pow(2, i) + Math.pow(2, j) + Math.pow(2, k) == n){
          arr.push(i, j, k);
          return arr;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

var array = countBits(8);

console.log(array.length+":", array); // 1: [3]
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I guess my method is a lot of brute force, because I'm so new, but I wanted to do it this way just so I get the hang of figuring out algorithms on my own.

Comment: If @Isaac's solution works for all cases as you expect, it is probably more efficient than mine, as it minifies the number of tries, but I'm not sure it gives the same result. Anyway, don't forget to declare the variables inside the function as in my answer.